# In what way does general relativity predict gravitational waves?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, gravitational-waves, linearized-theory

When people say that general relativity predicts gravitational waves, how so?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159159/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

In a mathematically analogous way that Maxwell's equation predicts electromagnetic waves.

You could [start here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.05974) and references therein:

> A conserved stress energy tensor for weak field gravitational waves propagating in vacuum is derived directly from the linearized wave equation alone, for an arbitrary gauge using standard general relativity. In any harmonic gauge, the form of the tensor leads directly to the classical expression for the outgoing wave energy. The method described here, however, is a much simpler, shorter, and more physically motivated approach than is the customary procedure, which involves a lengthy and cumbersome second-order (in wave-amplitude) calculation starting with the Einstein tensor.